# Can't generate <td> structure with recursive ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm having some difficulties generating the desired table structure with a nest ng-repeat. I have a table header for each day of the week and I want to display three shifts in the `<td>` beneath that. Currently I solve this with three `<span>`'s in one `<td>`, but I would like to generate three `<td>`'s for each shift in on day. My html code with the repeats is:

```
<div>
    <table>
    <caption>Week: {{ week }}</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th ng-repeat="day in days">
                <span>{{day.Date}}/{{ month }}/{{ year }}</span>    
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td ng-repeat="day in days">
                    <span ng-repeat="shift in shifts">{{shift.Name}}</span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I have tried `<th colspan="3">` with different placement of "day in days" repeats, but I can't seem to get the wanted structure for the table body:

```
<tr>
    <td>shift1</td>
    <td>shift2</td>
    <td>shift3</td>

    <td>shift1</td>
    <td>shift2</td>
    <td>shift3</td>

    <td>shift1</td>
    <td>shift2</td>
    <td>shift3</td>

    <td>shift1</td>
    <td>shift2</td>
    <td>shift3</td>

    <td>shift1</td>
    <td>shift2</td>
    <td>shift3</td>

    <td>shift1</td>
    <td>shift2</td>
    <td>shift3</td>
</tr>
```

My question is: how can I rewrite my current code with the `<span>`'s so that it generates the wanted structure above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create new plain list in your model to iterate over and use it instead of using nested loops. If data is to be changed then you can watch changes of dependent properties and reassemble plain list for each change. Something like this:

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('app',[]).
  controller('appController', function($scope) {
    var i, j;

    $scope.week = 1;
    $scope.days = [{
      day: 1,
      month: 2,
      year: 2014
    }, {
      day: 2,
      month: 2,
      year: 2014
    }, {
      day: 3,
      month: 2,
      year: 2014
    }];

    $scope.shifts = ['Shift1', 'Shift2', 'Shift3'];

    // Create new plain list each time shifts is changed
    $scope.$watchCollection('shifts', function() {
      $scope.daysShifts = [];
      for(i=0; i<$scope.days.length; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<$scope.shifts.length; j++) {
          $scope.daysShifts.push({
            name: $scope.shifts[j]  
          });
        }
      }
    });

    $scope.addShift = function() {
      $scope.shifts.push('Shift'+($scope.shifts.length+1));
    }
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.2.11" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.11/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="appController">
    <div>
      <table>
        <caption>Week: {{week}}</caption>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="day in days" colspan="{{shifts.length}}">
              <span>{{day.day}}/{{day.month}}/{{day.year}}</span>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td ng-repeat="dayShift in daysShifts">
              <span>{{dayShift.name}}</span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

    <button ng-click="addShift()">Add Shift</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/zZYrurhp3HQA9Jp9QHDo?p=preview

Comment: I don't think it is possible to get rid of the nested loop. Your example has one as well ;). It does however solve my problem so I am accepting this as the right answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your problem correctly then I think you are looking for `ng-repeat-start` & `ng-repeat-stop`.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
       <table border="1">
           <tr>
               <td ng-repeat-start="day in days" ng-show="false"></td>
               <td ng-repeat="shift in day.shifts" ng-repeat-end>shift{{shift}}</td>
           </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS Controller:

```
function ExampleCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.days = [
       {
           shifts: ["1","2","3"]
       },
       {
           shifts: ["1","2","3"]
       },
       {
           shifts: ["1","2","3"]
       },
       {
           shifts: ["1","2","3"]
       },
       {
           shifts: ["1","2","3"]
       }
   ];
}
```

and the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z7MEM/)

shifts outside days object: [Fiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/z7MEM/1/)

Comment: I think you paste the wrong fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/z7MEM/ ;) but good answer!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have indeed tried ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end. The problem is that the shifts array isn't in the day array. Since shifts are always the same I don't want to store them in the days array. I get this data from an API and that would mean that for every day I would have to add the same shifts. I can however create a new list in my controller like Vadim suggest below.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for getting back. This still doesn't solve my problem. As I showed in my example, I want the days in the table header and the shifts in the table body. This means they end up in a different tablerow.